# Nested Json array to objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

We are working on an integration tool, which is generating below JSON which is creating an array of objects instead of objects, our end application doesn't support this array structure, we cannot change the structure in the Integration tool, but we can add javascript which can perform this action. I have added current and expected JSON payloads. Brackets inside dataReq segment need to be removed thanks in advance!

**Current Json:**

```
{
    "abc": [
        {
            "abcId": "1",
            "dataReq": [
                {
                    "url": "/api.css.com",
                    "body": {
                        "desc": "Sprint",
                        "na": "Customer Data",
                        "tzone": "America/Los_Angeles"
                    },
                    "method": "PATCH",
                    "refData": "OP"
                },
                [
                    {
                        "url": "/api.css.com/v1",
                        "body": {
                            "day": "Monday",
                            "end": "18:00:00.000Z",
                            "start": "08:00:00.000Z",
                            "hours": "08",
                            "Type": "Normal"
                        },
                        "method": "PATCH",
                        "refData": "timeslotN"
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "/api.css.com/v2",
                        "body": {
                            "DayOfWeek": "Tuesday",
                            "EndTime": "18:00:00.000Z",
                            "StartTime": "08:00:00.000Z",
                            "hours": "09",
                            "Type": "Normal"
                        },
                        "method": "PATCH",
                        "refData": "timeslotN"
                    }
                ],
                {
                    "url": "/api.css.com/v3",
                    "body": {
                        "Name": "Spirit2",
                        "Type": "murchast",
                        "Parent": {
                            "accID": "2"
                        },
                        "street": "CR Steet",
                        "city": "NYK",
                        "state": null,
                        "postal": "9020",
                        "state": null,
                        "country": "LZ",
                    },
                    "method": "PATCH",
                    "refData": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "url": "/api.css.com/v4",
                    "body": {
                        "account": "12321",
                        "state": {
                            "statecode": "311"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "PATCH",
                    "refData": "acst"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected JSON:**

```
{
    "abc": [
        {
            "abcId": "1",
            "dataReq": [
                {
                    "url": "/api.css.com",
                    "body": {
                        "desc": "Sprint",
                        "na": "Customer Data",
                        "tzone": "America/Los_Angeles"
                    },
                    "method": "PATCH",
                    "refData": "OP"
                },
                {
                        "url": "/api.css.com/v1",
                        "body": {
                            "day": "Monday",
                            "end": "18:00:00.000Z",
                            "start": "08:00:00.000Z",
                            "hours": "08",
                            "Type": "Normal"
                        },
                        "method": "PATCH",
                        "refData": "timeslotN"
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "/api.css.com/v2",
                        "body": {
                            "DayOfWeek": "Tuesday",
                            "EndTime": "18:00:00.000Z",
                            "StartTime": "08:00:00.000Z",
                            "hours": "09",
                            "Type": "Normal"
                        },
                        "method": "PATCH",
                        "refData": "timeslotN"
                    },
                {
                    "url": "/api.css.com/v3",
                    "body": {
                        "Name": "Spirit2",
                        "Type": "murchast",
                        "Parent": {
                            "accID": "2"
                        },
                        "street": "CR Steet",
                        "city": "NYK",
                        "state": null,
                        "postal": "9020",
                        "state": null,
                        "country": "LZ",
                    },
                    "method": "PATCH",
                    "refData": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "url": "/api.css.com/v4",
                    "body": {
                        "account": "12321",
                        "state": {
                            "statecode": "311"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "PATCH",
                    "refData": "acst"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two? It's really hard to tell at the moment

Comment: The answer to this is always to fix the problem at the source. Hacking it on the client results in twice the mess that needs to be maintained. It's especially in need of fixing because the first item in the list is an object and the rest are within an array - the source is really busted and needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try using `Array#flatMap`.

You can simply use `Array#flatMap` to flatten the `dataReq` array.

> `data.abc[0].dataReq = data.abc[0].dataReq.flatMap((d) => d);`

```js
const data={abc:[{abcId:"1",dataReq:[{url:"/api.css.com",body:{desc:"Sprint",na:"Customer Data",tzone:"America/Los_Angeles"},method:"PATCH",refData:"OP"},[{url:"/api.css.com/v1",body:{day:"Monday",end:"18:00:00.000Z",start:"08:00:00.000Z",hours:"08",Type:"Normal"},method:"PATCH",refData:"timeslotN"},{url:"/api.css.com/v2",body:{DayOfWeek:"Tuesday",EndTime:"18:00:00.000Z",StartTime:"08:00:00.000Z",hours:"09",Type:"Normal"},method:"PATCH",refData:"timeslotN"}],{url:"/api.css.com/v3",body:{Name:"Spirit2",Type:"murchast",Parent:{accID:"2"},street:"CR Steet",city:"NYK",state:null,postal:"9020",state:null,country:"LZ"},method:"PATCH",refData:"Account"},{url:"/api.css.com/v4",body:{account:"12321",state:{statecode:"311"}},method:"PATCH",refData:"acst"}]}]};

data.abc[0].dataReq = data.abc[0].dataReq.flatMap((d) => d);

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox Please don't make unnecessary edits

Comment: Please may you stop using headings for text which is not a heading?

Comment: @evolutionxbox That is a heading according to me.

Comment: What is it a heading for? Then, please may you add some explanation to the answer so that the heading has something to be a heading of?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It is just to draw attention so that anyone can quickly comprehend what the answer is about. Its a personal preference I guess no one should have a problem with that.

Comment: Apologies. I have an issue with answers which are a single line of text as a heading. The edits are much appreciated. thanks for putting up with me

Answer (score 0):

Here is an generic solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan).

This solution will pull double nested arrays one level up.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data1 = { abc: [ { abcId: '1', dataReq: [ { url: '/api.css.com', body: { desc: 'Sprint', na: 'Customer Data', tzone: 'America/Los_Angeles' }, method: 'PATCH', refData: 'OP' }, [ { url: '/api.css.com/v1', body: { day: 'Monday', end: '18:00:00.000Z', start: '08:00:00.000Z', hours: '08', Type: 'Normal' }, method: 'PATCH', refData: 'timeslotN' }, { url: '/api.css.com/v2', body: { DayOfWeek: 'Tuesday', EndTime: '18:00:00.000Z', StartTime: '08:00:00.000Z', hours: '09', Type: 'Normal' }, method: 'PATCH', refData: 'timeslotN' } ], { url: '/api.css.com/v3', body: { Name: 'Spirit2', Type: 'murchast', Parent: { accID: '2' }, street: 'CR Steet', city: 'NYK', state: null, postal: '9020', state: null, country: 'LZ' }, method: 'PATCH', refData: 'Account' }, { url: '/api.css.com/v4', body: { account: '12321', state: { statecode: '311' } }, method: 'PATCH', refData: 'acst' } ] } ] };

const modify = objectScan(['**.*[*][*]'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ parent, gparent, property, gproperty }) => {
    gparent.splice(gproperty + 1, 0, parent[property]);
    parent.splice(property, 1);
    if (parent.length === 0) {
      gparent.splice(gproperty, 1);
    }
  }
});

console.log(modify(data1));
// => 2

console.log(data1);
// => { abc: [ { abcId: '1', dataReq: [ { url: '/api.css.com', body: { desc: 'Sprint', na: 'Customer Data', tzone: 'America/Los_Angeles' }, method: 'PATCH', refData: 'OP' }, { url: '/api.css.com/v1', body: { day: 'Monday', end: '18:00:00.000Z', start: '08:00:00.000Z', hours: '08', Type: 'Normal' }, method: 'PATCH', refData: 'timeslotN' }, { url: '/api.css.com/v2', body: { DayOfWeek: 'Tuesday', EndTime: '18:00:00.000Z', StartTime: '08:00:00.000Z', hours: '09', Type: 'Normal' }, method: 'PATCH', refData: 'timeslotN' }, { url: '/api.css.com/v3', body: { Name: 'Spirit2', Type: 'murchast', Parent: { accID: '2' }, street: 'CR Steet', city: 'NYK', state: null, postal: '9020', country: 'LZ' }, method: 'PATCH', refData: 'Account' }, { url: '/api.css.com/v4', body: { account: '12321', state: { statecode: '311' } }, method: 'PATCH', refData: 'acst' } ] } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@15.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Here is an example that makes it a bit clearer what is going on

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data2 = { a: { b: [[1, [2, 3]], { c: 4 }] }, d: [{ e: 5 }, 6, [7, 8]] };

const modify = objectScan(['**.*[*][*]'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ parent, gparent, property, gproperty }) => {
    gparent.splice(gproperty + 1, 0, parent[property]);
    parent.splice(property, 1);
    if (parent.length === 0) {
      gparent.splice(gproperty, 1);
    }
  }
});

console.log(modify(data2));
// => 4

console.log(data2);
// => { a: { b: [ 1, [ 2, 3 ], { c: 4 } ] }, d: [ { e: 5 }, 6, 7, 8 ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@15.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)